# onEditorCreated not supported on mat-quill

Tags: angular, typescript, quill

Event onEditorCreated is not emitted by any applicable directives nor by mat-quill element

```
      <mat-quill
        [(ngModel)]="desc.inputValue"
        (onEditorCreated)="createQuill($event)"
        (ngModelChange)="setDescriptionValidityFor(desc.descriptionUniqueIdentifier)"
        [disabled]="readOnly" theme="bubble">
      </mat-quill>
```

I know onEditorCreated is supported on the regular quill-editor but curious if there was a workaround.

Comment: What Angular library for Quill do you use?

Comment: https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill-example
https://killercodemonkey.github.io/ngx-quill-example/